# How to use BoundedFifoBuffer in Java?

Tags: java, collections, buffer, fifo, bounds

I am new to `java` and want to use `BoundedFifoBuffer`. But don't know how to use it.Can I get a running example of `BoundedFifoBuffer`?

Comment: `BoundedFifoBuffer ` is a very efficient implementation of Buffer that is of a fixed size and I want to use it in my program to make efficient buffer with bounded size..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a process I followed,

Download a binary `.jar` file ( [commons-collections-3.2.1.jar](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1/))and add it to build path it in my java project.Here is sample program

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.Buffer;
import org.apache.commons.collections.BufferOverflowException;
import org.apache.commons.collections.BufferUtils;
import org.apache.commons.collections.buffer.BoundedFifoBuffer;

public class DataReader {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Buffer fifo = BufferUtils.synchronizedBuffer(new BoundedFifoBuffer(100));
    int i;
    while (true) {
        try {
            for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                fifo.add(i);
            }
        } catch (BufferOverflowException e) {
            System.out.println("fifosize = " + fifo.size());
            System.out.println("before fifo = " + fifo.toString());
            fifo.removeAll(fifo);
            System.out.println("afer removeAll fifo size= " + fifo.size());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

}
```